# javascripts default replace function not working in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have simple nextjs app and I am trying to use javascript replace function to replace "-" with empty space " ". But I am getting error as TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined. Here is the code

```
import {useRouter} from 'next/router';
import Layout from '../../components/MyLayout';




 const Post = () => {
    const router = useRouter();

    let resString = router.query.id.replace("-", " ");



    return(
        <Layout>
            <h1>{resString}</h1>
            <p>This is the blog post content.</p>
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default Post;
```

[image]

Comment: Well the query string is undefined. `const resString = router.query.string ? router.query.string.replace("-", " "): '';`

Comment: sorry its router.query.id not string but still I am getting same error when I changed it to id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that if the query string is empty you does not have the `string` property.

First you have to check that the property exists and than use `.replace()` like in the following example:

```
let resString = router.query.id ? router.query.id.replace("-", " ") : "";
```

Also note that you have to use a regex like in the following example to actually replace all the occurrences:

```
router.query.id.replace(/-/g, " ");
```

Comment: yes I did that but replacement is not happening . I checked the type of router.query.id its saying its a string but I am not able to call replace function on it . when I try normal string it works.

Comment: I have added an image

Comment: I tried toString() to convert it to string even this function its showing error

Comment: Edited with the solution of the last problem you noticed... use the regex as explained here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: thanks it worked . But can you explain to me why it didnt work. I am curious

Comment: I just quote what is in the link: `If you are replacing a value (and not a regular expression), only the first instance of the value will be replaced. To replace all occurrences of a specified value, use the global (g) modifier (see "More Examples" below).`